Good source or list of 3d parametric (u,v) surfaces?
I am trying to find a list of as many (u,v) equations for 3d parametric surfaces as possible. I am using Desmos 3d graphing calculator to visualize each of these.So far I have the following:   
Sphere: ($\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\sin\left(u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(u\right)$) 
Ellipsoid: $\left(a\cos\left(u\right)\sin\left(v\right),b\cos\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),c\sin\left(u\right)\right)$ 
Elliptic Cone: $\left(a\cos\left(u\right)\sin\left(v\right),b\cos\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),c\cos\left(u\right)\right)$  
The following differ only by the coefficient inside the trig functions.  
Pillow: $\left(\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\sin\left(5u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(5u\right)\right)$  
Similar to "Pillow" except top is rotated 90 degrees and forms a hump rather than two points (Kind of like a guitar pick but wider at the base): $\left(\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\sin\left(2u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(2u\right)\right)$  
Similar to above but pinched inward along y-axis:
$\left(\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\sin\left(4u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(2u\right)\right)$  
Multifaceted Surface (not sure how to describe):
$(\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),1\sin\left(4u\right)\sin\left(v\right),1\cos\left(3u\right))$  
Similar to above (kind of like a pencil gripper): $\left(\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\sin\left(2.2u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(2.5u\right)\right)$  
Unsure what to call: $\left(\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\sin\left(5.5u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(2.5u\right)\right)$  
Unsure what to call: $\left(\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\sin\left(2.5u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(5.5u\right)\right)$  
By default I have the u and the v domains set to 0 to 2$\pi$ for each of the above surfaces.  
The 3d modeling software Blender comes with these (u,v) surfaces as presets.  
Bonbon (looks more like beads if you extend the u,v domains beyond 0 to 2$\pi$):  $\left(u,\cos\left(u\right)\cdot\sin\left(v\right),\cos\left(u\right)\cdot\cos\left(v\right)\right)$ 
Boy's Surface: $\left(\frac{2}{3}\left(\cos\left(u\right)\cdot\cos\left(2v\right)+\sqrt{2}\cdot\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right)\right)\cdot\frac{\cos\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{2}-\sin\left(2u\right)\cdot\sin\left(3v\right)},\sqrt{2}-\sin\left(2u\right)\cdot\sin\left(3v\right),\frac{2}{3}\left(\cos\left(u\right)\cdot\sin\left(2v\right)-\sqrt{2}\cdot\sin\left(u\right)\cdot\sin\left(v\right)\right)\cdot\frac{\cos\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{2}-\sin\left(2u\right)\cdot\sin\left(3v\right)}\right)$ 
Domain of u and v are from 0 to $\pi$.  
(Blender incorrectly calls this) Catalan's Surface:
($\left(u\sin\left(u\right)\cosh\left(v\right),4\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}u\right)\sinh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right),1-\cos\left(u\right)\cdot\cosh\left(v\right)\right)$) 
Domain of u -$\pi$ to 3$\pi$, domain of v -2 to 2.  
Catalan's Surface (actual equation from WolframMathworld):
$\left(u-\sin\left(u\right)\cosh\left(v\right),1-\cos\left(u\right)\cosh\left(v\right),4\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}u\right)\sinh\left(\frac{1}{2}v\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u -4$\pi$ to 4$\pi$, domain of v 0 to 2.  
Catenoid: $\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cdot\cos\left(u\right),v,2\cdot\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(u\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u, v -$\pi$ to 2$\pi$.  
Clifford Torus: $\left(\frac{\cos\left(u+v\right)}{\sqrt{2}+\cos\left(v-u\right)},\frac{\sin\left(v-u\right)}{\sqrt{2}+\cos\left(v-u\right)},\frac{\sin\left(u+v\right)}{\sqrt{2}+\cos\left(v-u\right)}\right)$ 
Domain of u 0 to $\pi$, domain of v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
Cochlea (basically just a helix scaled by v in x and y components): $\left(v\cos\left(u\right),v\sin\left(u\right),0.4u\right)$ 
Domain of u 0 to 4$\pi$, domain of v 0 to 1.  
Cosinus: $\left(u,\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(u^{2}+v^{2}\right)\right)}{2},v\right)$ 
Domain of u,v -1 to 1.  
Dini: $\left(\cos\left(u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\sin\left(u\right)\sin\left(v\right),\left(\cos\left(v\right)+\log\left(\tan\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)+1\cdot10^{-2}\right)\right)+0.2u\right)$ 
Domain of u 0 to 4$\pi$, domain of v 0 to 2.  
Enneper: $\left(u-\frac{u^{3}}{3}+uv^{2},u^{2}-v^{2},v-\frac{v^{3}}{3}+vu^{2}\right)$ 
Domain of u, v -$\pi$ to $\pi$.  
Hexahedron: $\left(15\cos\left(v\right)^{3}\cos\left(u\right)^{3},15\sin\left(u\right)^{3},15\sin\left(v\right)^{3}\cos\left(u\right)^{3}\right)$ 
Domain of u -$\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, domain of v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
Hyperhelicoidal: $\left(10\frac{\sinh\left(v\right)\cos\left(3u\right)}{1+\cosh\left(u\right)\cosh\left(v\right)},10\frac{\cosh\left(v\right)\sinh\left(u\right)}{1+\cosh\left(u\right)\cosh\left(v\right)},10\frac{\sinh\left(v\right)\sin\left(3u\right)}{1+\cosh\left(u\right)\cosh\left(v\right)}\right)$ 
Domain of u, v -$\pi$ to $\pi$.  
Klein Bottle: $\left(\left(3\left(1+\sin\left(v\right)\right)+2\left(1-\frac{\cos\left(v\right)}{2}\right)\cos\left(u\right)\right)\cos\left(v\right),\left(4+2\left(1-\frac{\cos\left(v\right)}{2}\right)\cos\left(u\right)\right)\sin\left(v\right),-2\left(1-\frac{\cos\left(v\right)}{2}\right)\sin\left(u\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u,v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
Möbius Strip: $\left(\cos\left(v\right)+u\cos\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cos\left(v\right),u\sin\left(\frac{v}{2}\right),\sin\left(v\right)+u\cos\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\sin\left(v\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u 0 to 2$\pi$, domain of v -1 to 1.  
Pseudo-catenoid: $\left(2.2\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cos\left(u\right)\right),1.51166\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\sin\left(u\right)\sin\left(\left(2.2\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cos\left(u\right)\right)-11.0404\right)\cdot\frac{2\pi}{22.0513}\right)+1.8v\cos\left(\left(2.2\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cos\left(u\right)\right)-11.0404\right)\cdot\frac{2\pi}{22.0513}\right)\right),1.51166\cdot\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(\left(2.2\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cos\left(u\right)\right)-11.0404\right)\cdot\frac{2\pi}{22.0513}\right)-1.8v\sin\left(\left(2.2\left(\left(\left(\left(2\cosh\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)\cos\left(u\right)-11.0404\right)\cdot\frac{2\pi}{22.0513}\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u, v -$\pi$ to $\pi$.  
Pseudosphere: $\left(\cos\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right)+\sin\left(\left(\sin\left(u\right)+1\right)\cdot2\pi\right),4\sin\left(u\right),\cos\left(u\right)\sin\left(v\right)+\cos\left(\left(\sin\left(u\right)+1\right)\cdot2\pi\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u -$\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, domain of v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
Ridged Torus: $\left(a\cos\left(u\right)+\left(b\sin\left(f\cdot u\right)+c\right)\cdot\cos\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),a\sin\left(u\right)+\left(b\sin\left(fu\right)+\right)\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right),\left(\sin\left(fu\right)+c\right)\sin\left(v\right)\right)$ 
Where a,b,c,f are constants. Domain of u, v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
Shell: $\left(\cos\left(v\right)\left(1+\cos\left(u\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{v}{8}\right),\sin\left(u\right)\sin\left(\frac{v}{8}\right)+1.5\cos\left(\frac{v}{8}\right),\sin\left(v\right)\left(1+\cos\left(u\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{v}{8}\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u 0 to 2$\pi$, domain of v 0 to 10$\pi$.  
"Sine" (looks like a box beveled and pushed in weirdly): $\left(\sin\left(u\right),\sin\left(v\right),\sin\left(u+v\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u, v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
Twisted Torus: $\left(\cos\left(u\right)\left(6-\left(\frac{5}{4}+\sin\left(3v\right)\right)\sin\left(v-3u\right)\right),\left(6-\left(\frac{5}{4}+\sin\left(3v\right)\right)\sin\left(v-3u\right)\right)\sin\left(u\right),-\cos\left(v-3u\right)\left(\frac{5}{4}+\sin\left(3v\right)\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u, v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
That covers all of the interesting blender surfaces, here are the remaining that I know. 
Like a piece of rope knotted three times: $\left(2+\sin\left(v\right)\cos\left(u\right),2+\sin\left(v\right)\sin\left(u\right),u+\cos\left(v\right)\right)$ 
Domain of u, v 0 to 2$\pi$.  
Trefoil Knot (From Wikipedia): $\left(\frac{5\sin\left(3u\right)}{2+\cos\left(v\right)},\frac{5\left(\sin\left(u\right)+2\sin\left(2u\right)\right)}{\left(2+\cos\left(v+\frac{2}{3}\pi\right)\right)},\frac{5}{2}\cdot\left(\cos\left(u\right)-2\cos\left(2u\right)\right)\cdot\left(2+\cos\left(v\right)\right)\cdot\frac{\left(2+\cos\left(v+\frac{2}{3}\pi\right)\right)}{4}\right)$ 
Domain of u, v -$\pi$ to 3$\pi$.  
What sources would you recommend to find as many more parametric (u,v) surfaces as possible? I am already aware of Wolfram Mathworld. Additionally, I am most interested in surfaces with a closed interior like the Hexahedron, Ridged Torus, Twisted Torus, Pillow, and Klein Bottle, Or knot-like surfaces that close without any loose ends like the Möbius Strip, and Trefoil Knot.

Do you know the mathcurve site ?
